# One cold night for (...)

Tags: story, password

There is a great magnificent wall to your east

`Look at wall`
There is a small gate in the wall.

`Open gate`
The gate is locked.

`Unlock gate`
The gate is still locked.

`Look`
You see a small key laying next to a weather beaten fisherman in a gray tunic leaning against a wall.  The wall has a gate in it.

`Pick up key`
As you been over to grab the key the fisherman's foot springs around as quick as a whip and picks up the key with his smallest toe.

`Talk to fisherman`
You begin to introduce yourself "Hello sir my name is .... " but the fisherman interrupts:
"Your an adventurer."
You quickly reply "How did you know?"
"You seem to have an illusion of free will about you, a sense of mystery in your eye, and I can access any player's character sheet" he says with a grin.
"Now If you want to get past this wall and onto the next challenge in this outdated form of entertainment you must tell me the password which for simplicity's sake is your name."

`Say your name`

***Wait! What is your name?***

Comment: Are the spelling/grammatical errors intentional?

Comment: Yes.  Most of then grammar mistakes are intentional.  The rest are due to my own stupidity and my local school system.

Comment: And a flying kick launched against the fisherman followed by a dex check isn't an option ;)

Comment: +1 for recalling me the beautiful time of textual adventures...

Comment: I hope this isn't a semi-interactive... I think those are considered bad quality now...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I say

> My name is "Your An Adventurer"

This is my name because

> I was about to say this and was shocked when he said it first.

Comment: Is that the intended solution? If so, poor puzzle IMHO...

Comment: Wouldn't it be just "An Adventurer" with your(sic) being the statement from the man?

Answer (score 2):

From the nature of the conversation and style of it, your name is...

> adventurer from the Adventures of Zork.

as the main character was

> unnamed.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to look at it is...

> say "my name is ben-Nabiy Derush"